# The name 'txtCategName' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Using ASP.NET Web Forms

Basically what I'm trying to do in this code is to take the name of the Category that the user inputs (using txtCategName) then save it and below display all Categories that were created (using lvCategs)

Below is my aspx file

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Categories.aspx.cs" Inherits="Categories" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <!-- Page-Level Plugin CSS - Tables -->
    <link href="css/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/panel-nav.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphPage" runat="Server">


    <h3 class="page-header">Categories<asp:Label runat="server" ID="CategoryDetails"></asp:Label></h3>



    <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Administrative Actions
                </div>

                <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button class="btn btn-primary " style="" onclick="return false;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addSection">
                        Create Category
                    </button>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="addSection" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Categories <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Add Category</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group input-group" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <label class="control-label">Category Name</label>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCategName" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Save changes" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.modal-content -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.modal -->


                        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvPageTabs">
                            <LayoutTemplate>
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="draggableTab">
                                    <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </LayoutTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li class="tab-heading">
                                    <a href='<%# "#"+ Eval("name").ToString().ToLower().Replace(" ", "-") %>' data-toggle="tab"><%# Eval("name") %> </a>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                    </div>
                </div>






    <asp:ListView ID="lvCategs" OnItemDeleting="lvCategs_ItemDeleting" OnItemCommand="lvCategs_ItemCommand" DataKeyNames="category_id" runat="server">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Categories Created
                        </div>
                        <div class="table table-bordered">
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead runat="server">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Date Created</th>
                                        <th>Category Name</th>
                                        <th>Edit/Delete Brand</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <td runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></td>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCategoryDateCreated" runat="server"
                                Text='<%#Eval("date_created") %>' /></td>

                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCategoryName" runat="server"
                                Text='<%#Eval("name") %>' /></td>


                        <td>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" CommandName="Edit" ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" />
                            <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" CommandName="Delete" ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" />



                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>

    <!-- Page-Level Plugin Scripts - Tables -->
    <script src="bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class Categories : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DisplayCategories();
        }
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            Category categ = new Category();
            categ.name = txtCategName.Text;
            categ.date_created = DateTime.Now;

            db.Categories.Add(categ);
            db.SaveChanges();
            DisplayCategories();
        }

    }

    protected void DisplayCategories()
    {
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            List<Category> categs = db.Categories.ToList();
            lvCategs.DataSource = categs.OrderByDescending(c => c.date_created);
            lvCategs.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void lvCategs_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            using (Entities db = new Entities())
            {

                int id = Convert.ToInt32(lvCategs.DataKeys[e.Item.DisplayIndex].Values["category_id"]);
                Category catg = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(b => b.category_id == id);
                db.Categories.Remove(catg);
                db.SaveChanges();
                DisplayCategories();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void lvCategs_ItemDeleting(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Although the code works fine, it still gives me the error `The name 'txtCategName' does not exist in the current context` and `The name 'lvCategs' does not exist in the current context` whenever I build the solution.

I copied the code and created a new file as some other solutions suggested but it still didn't work.

Comment: is it web application or web site?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Web site

Comment: Did you restart the VS?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Yes, multiple times

Comment: If you add another control to the form, this new control have same problem?

Comment: Yes the same problem occurs @MehdiDehghani

Comment: Did you have this problem with all your solutions?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Only with this solution so far...

Comment: Did you mean, if you create new one and add same master page, pages, ..., you have not any issue?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Yes I tried a whole new file with a default master page and had no errors such as this one

Comment: Maybe replacing the `web.config` helps you, can you replace new solution's web.config with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the class to _Categories wait for intellisense to complain it should ask you to rename the class back to Categories.

It is basically just a Visual Studio bug where is looses the connection between your mark up and the code behind.  Force it to give you an actual error and it will force intellisense to refresh and notice the connection again.

Comment: Alternatively you can delete the text box and recreating it by typing the entire mark up instead of copy and paste.  It should also force it to update.

Comment: I tried this unfortunately it did not resolve the problem

Comment: Try using a variable just to see if the error goes away.
`string test = txtCategName.Text;
using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            Category categ = new Category();
            categ.name = test;`

Comment: Actually what I did is what you told me again and again and it worked! Seemed like it was a bug from Visual Studio. Thanks for the help!